# Yii Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: yii

Getting this type of error on my host,but have no errors on my localhost. The error dissapears on the host when I display the values using relation name like `model.attribute`. What can be the problem?

Here is my **model**:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('ammount, currency_id, operation_type', 'required'),
        array('currency_id, operation_type, client_id, organization_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('creation_date, modification_date, ammount, ammount_usd', 'length', 'max'=>10),
    //array('ammount, currency_id, operation_type, client_id, organization_id,comment', 'safe'),

        array('ammount, ammount_usd, currency_id, operation_type, client_id, organization_id, currency,comment,
        operationType ,client, organization', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'client' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Client', 'client_id'),
        'currency' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Currencies', 'currency_id'),
        'organization' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Organizations', 'organization_id'),
        'operationType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'OperationType', 'operation_type'),
        'operationsMeta' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'OperationsMeta', 'operation_id'),
    );
}
```

here is the **view** file:

```
<h1>Управление операциями</h1>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.BootGridView',array(
    'id'=>'operations-grid',
    'type'=>'striped bordered',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    //'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'operationType',
            'value'=>'$data->operationType->name',
            'header'=>'Операция'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'creation_date',
            'type'=>'datetime',
            'header'=>'Дата создания'
        ),
        'ammount_usd:raw:Сумма',
        'comment:text:Комментарий',
        array(
            'name'=>'currency',
            'value'=>'$data->currency->short',
            'header'=>'Валюта',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'client',
            'value'=>'$data->client->fio',
            'header'=>'Клиент',
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'organization',
            'value'=>'$data->organization->name',
            'header'=>'Организация',
        ),

        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.BootButtonColumn',
            'header'=>'Action'
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: on what line is the error occurring?

Comment: while tracing found out that it's failing on the line with the $data->client->fio. fio is a virtual field that has a public getter in Client model. Strange that this code is working on local but not on host server

Comment: that would indicate that $data->client is empty, or there is no record there for that particular model?

Comment: there is data from the database. made a print_r of the $model before rendering the view.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to check filenames of your model classes! Because when you running your application under windows all filenames are case insensitive, but under linux based system Yii doesn't find them.

Comment: thx for the hint, will try it in the morning and let you know.